# python void loop() function like arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm new to python and I'm developing a raspberry pi program that will check a sever ever 2 min. i have the server check part working But, I'm not sure how to accomplish the repeat. For example in arduino there is `void loop()` function there I could wait to see if 2min have pass then call the sever check function without a problem. How would I accomplish this in python?

Comment: `while True:` will go in an endless loop

Comment: I need to also do other functions as well that would block the flow. would it not?

Comment: Why not just use crontab if you are working with raspberry pi and have Linux?

Comment: What I'm making is a digital signage program and it will display images and video fullscreen so this is just a small part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/34930820-running-things-regularly-cron

You can setup a script to run every 2 minutes